# How to add tailwind CSS to an exisiting react project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have an existing `React Project`. I had used the bootstrap classes earlier but now I want to replace it with the `Tailwind CSS`. I had already asked about my error here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623660/unable-to-upload-taiwind-css-in-react-project) but didn't get any response, so I want to know the process from the beginning.

You can also find more details related to the project in the shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623660/unable-to-upload-taiwind-css-in-react-project).

Thank you in Advance for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. Follow the official documentation and start using Tailwind. You can skip Step 1 as you have already created your React App.

Install Tailwind CSS in a React App : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: I had follwed the same steps brother, and got this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623660/unable-to-upload-taiwind-css-in-react-project

Comment: O! I just saw that. Try "npm install @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"

Comment: What does this command do?

Comment: It is a PostCSS compatibility package for versions above 7. Besides, if you are using VSCode, you will have to install the PostCSS extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss

Comment: Extension name -  PostCSS Language support , just to confirm?'

Comment: Yes. That's correct!

Comment: But its not working

Comment: Tailwind initially used to implement craco in order to run it properly with React. I have a repository which you can clone and run. See if that works. https://github.com/junaidanjum/react-tailwind

Clone and hit 'npm install'. If that works, you can also try using craco.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 I have answered  your previous question, you can give it a checkout at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623660/unable-to-upload-taiwind-css-in-react-project

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Tailwind CSS with postcss & autoprefixer

`yarn add -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

2. Generate tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js

`yarn tailwindcss init -p`

3. Modify tailwind.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

4. Add tailwind base, components and utilities to index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```